Laravel memory usage of deleting old applications model
I'm working in a Laravel 11 web application. I have a model called Application and a hasMany relationship to ApplicationEntry models. I need to find the Application, and delete the oldest entry. I'm concerned over the memory usage of the following and whether this is optimised?
**
 * Handle the event.
 */
public function handle(ProcessDuplicateApplication $event): void
{
    $application = Application::findOrFail($event->applicationId);

    if (! $application) {
        return;
    }

    Sleep::for(rand(0, 100))->milliseconds();

    if ($application->entries()->count() > 2) {
        $oldest = $application->entries()->oldest()->first();

        if ($oldest) {
            $oldest->delete();
        }
    }
}

This is the entries relationship
/**
 * Get the application entries that this model has
 */
public function entries(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(ApplicationEntry::class);
}


you are concerned over the memory usage of loading 2 models in memory?

Memory usage for my server is constantly going up. So yes. MySQL memory usage rising and not going down when processing thousands of jobs. Each job performs the above query. Is something being loaded into memory first?

the memory mysql is using to run or cache your queries has little to do with Laravel. how many workers do you have running in paralel?

I have 36 workers. Changing it to 24 or even 12 doesn't make much difference here. Memory usage still climbing despite having 500,000 jobs in my jobs table.

Just a concern, why have you added the Sleep?

Just to try and reduce the chances of read/write at the same time on the database. There's hundreds of thousands of jobs and lots of workers.

I'm a bit confused, does this climbing memory usage affect your server? do you experience slowdowns bc of it? does your server have swap memory? If the climbing memory usage is filling empty memory, what is the problem? is your mysql instance on the same machine as the application? If you want to optimize this maybe you can look into doing more in one job and dispatching less jobs. Jobs are usually used for intensive operations and I see none of that in this code.

If you have the database engine on the same machine as your Laravel workers, that is a big issue, change it right away, due to exactly your problem. Memory issues on the database should not affect another service outside code (you are sharing workers with a DB engine)
